# kcompactd high CPU usage

Tags: linux-kernel

kcompactd is spiking while we are PUTting a file using FTP to another host,  and the transfer rate is dropping.

```
    top - 18:39:59 up 31 days,  6:23,  4 users,  load average: 1.15, 0.42, 0.32
Tasks: 1947 total,   2 running, 1942 sleeping,   0 stopped,   3 zombie
%Cpu0  :  2.9 us, 29.4 sy,  0.0 ni, 66.7 id,  0.0 wa,  0.0 hi,  1.0 si,  0.0 st
%Cpu1  :  1.0 us, 13.7 sy,  0.0 ni, 80.4 id,  4.9 wa,  0.0 hi,  0.0 si,  0.0 st
%Cpu2  :  0.0 us, 23.5 sy,  0.0 ni, 75.5 id,  1.0 wa,  0.0 hi,  0.0 si,  0.0 st
%Cpu3  :  0.0 us, 44.3 sy,  0.0 ni, 55.7 id,  0.0 wa,  0.0 hi,  0.0 si,  0.0 st
KiB Mem:  82382288 total, 81858160 used,   524128 free,    38692 buffers
KiB Swap:  4194300 total,     9508 used,  4184792 free. 14808308 cached Mem

  PID USER      PR  NI    VIRT    RES    SHR S  %CPU  %MEM     TIME+ COMMAND
   32 root      20   0       0      0      0 R 88.57 0.000 289:18.19 kcompactd0
18324 root      20   0   44160   7452   5712 S 9.524 0.009   0:19.85 lftp
```

Why could that be?

OS is SLES12-SP3 running Kernel 4.4.162-94.72-default

```
/proc/meminfo
MemTotal:       82382284 kB
MemFree:          649840 kB
MemAvailable:   10539176 kB
Buffers:           41912 kB
Cached:         14042992 kB
SwapCached:          468 kB
Active:         21716412 kB
Inactive:        6664344 kB
Active(anon):   16632900 kB
Inactive(anon):  1822684 kB
Active(file):    5083512 kB
Inactive(file):  4841660 kB
Unevictable:          80 kB
Mlocked:              80 kB
SwapTotal:       4194300 kB
SwapFree:        4184324 kB
Dirty:               624 kB
Writeback:             0 kB
AnonPages:      14295500 kB
Mapped:           218488 kB
Shmem:           4159732 kB
Slab:             901184 kB
SReclaimable:     728604 kB
SUnreclaim:       172580 kB
KernelStack:       35520 kB
PageTables:       938124 kB
NFS_Unstable:          0 kB
Bounce:                0 kB
WritebackTmp:          0 kB
CommitLimit:    19785440 kB
Committed_AS:   29080800 kB
VmallocTotal:   34359738367 kB
VmallocUsed:           0 kB
VmallocChunk:          0 kB
HardwareCorrupted:     0 kB
AnonHugePages:         0 kB
HugePages_Total:   25000
HugePages_Free:     2223
HugePages_Rsvd:       18
HugePages_Surp:        0
Hugepagesize:       2048 kB
DirectMap4k:     5922752 kB
DirectMap2M:    30777344 kB
DirectMap1G:    49283072 kB
```

Comment: Hey just curious if you were using 9,000 byte packets. I seem to recall vaguely that can make Linux need to allocate 3-4 pages per packet instead of 1.

Comment: Nah we're not using jumbo frames that I'm aware of. However we've hit a similar issue again which seems to be related to memory mapping of files when backup runs over very large file. If there is less RAM available than the largest file, this seems to lead to complications. Since we were running mission critical stuff we didn't have time to experiment and just gave it more memory :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Updating the kernel fixed this BTW...